# Two-column, Word document that alternates left-to-right then top-to-bottom

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2011

I'm hoping to reproduce something akin to Facebook's timeline:

[image]

To do so, I figure that I need a two-column document (I know how to do this), where the flow alternates left-to-right, then top-to-bottom.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by flow? What would be the *trigger* to go from left to right instead of downward? What's the use of the document? What's the goal of the document? A lot more information on what you want to accomplish would help us determine if it's feasible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this with columns, but you could just make a 2 column table, and turn the borders off, then you are free to enter information on each side as you wish